# Android Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener Error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have spent my whole midnight oil. But yet to have a solution.
My problem with Spinner control.

(No problem with data binding. I am using android 4.2)

When clicked, it gets the following errors.

I have tried it out with the following options:
1> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts File adding 127.0.0.1 localhost
2>Changing in eclipse Window->Preferences->Android->DDMS set port with 8601 and Use ADBHOST option checked.(using this option i over come the "vm does not provide monitor information" problem but the  main thread is terminated.)

I also tried with different approach but nothing helped. 
Help from your end will be appreciated.

Main Activity Code:

```
package com.example.newapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Spinner ss=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    list.add("list 4");


    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.spinner1);


    ss.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    ss.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ss.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Message in Logcat:

```
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080001 type #0x12 is not valid
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2136)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:741)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:737)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:685)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:964)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:608)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17318)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
03-31 20:19:56.569: E/AndroidRuntime(7110):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing comes from this line:

```
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.spinner1);
```

You are trying to set an ID as layout for all spinner items which is not allowed obviously.

If your intention is to achieve different styling for your dropdown list items, you can use the method `setDropDownViewResource();` and pass a valid layout ID. Otherwise, just delete this line and your spinner will be displayed using the default theme.